# Find rownum from mySQL result set for ranking

Tags: php, mysql, select, nested

I have a table that stores scores from users of my game - what I want to be able to do if possible is find their rank using mySQL alone (because if the amount of players increases exponentially the php loop times to parse the entire database will increase dramatically).

So far I have been able to get this statement

```
select @rownum:=@rownum+1 'rank', s.* from top100 s, (select @rownum:=0) r order by score desc
```

to return a result set with rankings applied - what I then need to be able to do is find a single item within that using a subquery to find the players last insert_id from a previous insert.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t.*,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
          FROM top100 t2
         WHERE t2.score > t.score) AS rank
  FROM top100 t
 WHERE id = LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

Comment: Many thanks, sorry for the delay - had lots of other things to deal with :) I will give it a go soon

Comment: zerkms, should I just use your code and remove my own or so I use yours in conjunction with my own?

Comment: @mmuller: I think my query does the job, doesn't it?

Comment: Sorry, I have been away and not tried it still! But I will okay it and then try it out thanks